# Create C# class that is public inside the DLL but not accessible outside

Tags: c#, .net, class

Sorry if this question is confusing.  I have a public static class inside my project that I want accessible anywhere inside my application.  However, I don't want this class exposed when someone else references my DLL in another project.

Is it possible to do this?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the internal modifier on the class instead of public.  You can also make `assembly:[InternalsVisibleTo("SomeOtherAssembly")]` if you want to make the class accessible to another specific DLL.

Answer (score 5):

use [Internal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) classes as described in the link.

Answer (score 2):

Please read C# documentation at MSDN or if you can read some good book about .net basics.  You can specify `internal` specifier to make class visible inside a namespace.